# BigQuery SQL - Regex and collect as an Array

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a column that is a string of sizes, where there is spaces but some I want to keep, and then collect these into an array

e.g UK 8 US 9 EU 42

to

[UK 8,US 9,EU 42]

Im terrible at regex, how in standard SQL how would I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT col, REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(s, '([A-Z]+ [0-9]+)') arr
FROM (
  SELECT 'col' col, 'UK 8 US 9 EU 42' s
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks heaps Felipe!  Quick question as a BigQuery expert, spark (databricks) recently released a feature called 'Higher Order Functions' for SQL.  Which are brilliant for doing recursive transformations using a simple SQL / functional programming model.  Have the folk from BQ seen this and considering a similar capability?  UDFs exist but this is built in / very simple to express, language agnostic and optimised - be cool to see similar with BQ standard SQL too!  Loving BQ :)

Comment: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/higher-order-functions-lambda-functions.html

Comment: These functions can be expressed using standard SQL in BigQuery already. For example, `TRANSFORM(values, value -> value + key)` is equivalent to `ARRAY(SELECT value + key FROM UNNEST(value) AS value)`.

Comment: Hi Elliott, Super cool reply thank you I see!  I shall have a play then cheers!

Comment: Hi Elliott, Sorry to bother you is there an equivalent of a 'Pivot' fuction - if not explicitly, some other magicla BQ standard SQL way?